# Starting, stopping & refreshing timer javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGASp/1/) here where I'm starting/stopping/resetting a javascript timer.

The functionality needs to be a timer runs on a page. When the timer is up, it sends a message, then restarts. The stop button will stop the timer completely.

The fiddle above has the functionality I just described, however I feel like I'm not doing this correctly. Is `setTimeout` the correct way to create this timer? Should I use `setInterval` instead?

Secondly, my reset code looks like :

```
var onReset = function() {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        onStart();    
};
```

Is there a more elegant way to reset a timer in javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Your way of calling `setInterval()` recursively works, but you could also use `setInterval()` almost the same way. http://jsfiddle.net/4BF2p/1/

Comment: Your reset func is fine as well. That is exactly the right way to handle it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only improvement I can offer is for you to put it all in an encapsulated object, ask if you want an example. Or if you want to keep the structure you've got then change your onStart function to this to remove a bit of un-needed code.

```
var onStart = function() {

    timerHandle = setInterval(function() {
        $("#console").append("timer fired.. <br />");
    }, 2000);

};
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/qx6CM/